# TensorFlow model.fit: expected shape=(None, 100, 3), found shape=(100, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow and ML and I'm trying to create a GAN that will generate an array of 3 dimensions (output shape is 100, 3).

I have the following discriminator model:

```py
def make_discriminator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(input_shape=(100, 3), name="Input"))

    model.add(layers.Flatten(name="Flatten"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, name="Output"))

    return model
```

When using this model as such it works okay:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # generate fake data to test the discriminator with
    noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
    generator = make_generator_model()
    fake_data = generator(noise, training=False)

    # create the discriminator
    discriminator = make_discriminator_model()
    # test with fake data
    decision = discriminator(fake_data)
    print(decision)
```

Outputs: `tf.Tensor([[0.0120331]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)`

However when training with `model.fit`, I get `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 100, 3), found shape=(100, 3)`. This is the training code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    generator = make_generator_model()
    discriminator = make_discriminator_model()

    # constants
    seed = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
    epochs = 5

    # generate fake data
    fake_data = generator(seed, training=False)

    # load dataset
    dataset = all_data(max_size=10_000)
    # split dataset into training (80%) and testing (20%)
    training_dataset = dataset[:8000]
    test_dataset = dataset[8000:]

    # use optimizer and loss function
    discriminator.compile(
        loss=losses.Hinge(),
        optimizer="adam",
        metrics=tf.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.0)
    )

    discriminator.summary()

    # convert training data into a Dataset
    input_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_dataset[:6000])
    input_validation = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_dataset[6000:])
    # train discriminator
    discriminator.fit(input_dataset, epochs=epochs, validation_data=input_validation)
```

I understand that it's expecting the shape `None, 100, 3` and is getting the shape `100, 3` but I don't understand why it's adding `None` to the front of the shape when using `model.fit`.

Answer (score 1):

The leading `None` represents the batch dimension. By specifying `input_shape=(100, 3)`, you are telling the model that it should expect a batch of unknown number of samples, where each sample is of shape `(100,3)`.

However, what you are feeding to it is a tensor of shape `(100,3)`, which it interprets as "a batch of 100 samples each of shape `(3,)`" and complains. If 100 is actually the number of samples in a batch, you'll need to specify `input_shape=(3,)`. Otherwise, if `(100,3)` is the sample shape and there is indeed only one sample in the batch, you'll need to expand the tensor in the first dimension to make it `(1,100,3)`.